# How to insert dynamically developed string query in to with column function scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to automate the process of changing the column values of pos column generated when using posexplode function:
Below is my code:

```
val someDF = Seq(
  (8, "bat","1a","2a"),
  (64, "mouse","1b","2b"),
  (-27, "horse","1c","2c")
).toDF("number", "word","cat1","cat2")

val col2 =someDF.columns.slice(2,10)
val collist=col2.mkString(",")
val fg=col2.zipWithIndex
someDF.createOrReplaceTempView("mydf")

val newDf=spark.sql("""select *,posexplode(array("""+collist+""")) from mydf""")


val myac=fg.map({case (f,i)=>".when(newDf("+"\""+"pos"+"\"" +")" + "===" + i +","+"regexp_replace(col("+"\""+"pos"+"\""+"),"+ "\""+i+"\""+"," +"\""+f+"\""+"))"}).mkString("").stripPrefix(".")
```

when tried to execute in static way as below it works fine:

```
newDf.withColumn("Category", when(newDf("pos")===0, regexp_replace(col("pos"),"0","cat1")).when(newDf("pos")===1, regexp_replace(col("pos"),"1","cat2")))
output:
------+-----+----+----+---+---+--------+
|number| word|cat1|cat2|pos|col|Category|
+------+-----+----+----+---+---+--------+
|     8|  bat|  1a|  2a|  0| 1a|    cat1|
|     8|  bat|  1a|  2a|  1| 2a|    cat2|
|    64|mouse|  1b|  2b|  0| 1b|    cat1|
|    64|mouse|  1b|  2b|  1| 2b|    cat2|
|   -27|horse|  1c|  2c|  0| 1c|    cat1|
|   -27|horse|  1c|  2c|  1| 2c|    cat2|
+------+-----+----+----+---+---+--------+
```

goal is to Achieve the same in dynamic way  which is failing

```
val newdf1=newDf.withcolumn("Category",myac)
val newdf1=newDf.withColumn("Level",s"${myac}") 

ERROR:command-1732554743656721:1: error: type mismatch;
found   : String
required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

Any idea or suggestion how to solve this problem will be helpful

Comment: Can you post full code with same data ?

Comment: format your question properly before asking. dont be hurry provide data code examples everytime. at least I could not able to understand what you are asking. Most importantly code  should not be in bold. Rather you can give tildes See [How to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :Review

Comment: posted the full code.@Srinivas

Comment: Thank you ,made changes as suggested @RamGhadiyaram

Comment: Maybe try to minimize code samples, so that people could get an idea where is a problem.

Comment: The last part is where i am facing issue just edited for better readability.@AlexeyNovakov

Answer (score 0):

Your `myac` variable is of type String. if you want to use this variable inside withColumn you have to use`lit()` function. `lit` function convert your string value to column.

Your error says you are passing string, but its required column.

```
ERROR:command-1732554743656721:1: error: type mismatch; found : String required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column newDf.withColumn("Level",s"${myac}")
```

Check below.

```
myac: String = when(newDf("pos")===0,regexp_replace(col("pos"),"0","hat")).when(newDf("pos")===1,regexp_replace(col("pos"),"1","cat"))

newDf.withColumn("Level",lit(s"${myac}")) // here I have changed s"${myac}" to lit(s"${myac}"
```